# jScroll not adding content when page is in full width, works switching to mobile view

Tags: javascript, infinite-scroll

I am using jScroll for infinite scrolling. I have a page with 3x3 bootstrap cards with images inside. I added the paginator links to the bottom after the foreach loop that renders the post. What happens is jScroll doesn't trigger anything with this kind of view while if I switch to a mobile view from devtools likefor example Galaxy S5 or iPhone 6 (where then the view will switch to one column instead of three) then jScroll will work.
I think probably the package is waiting for some event that never occurs, any clue?

Comment: Did you set any code to detect the viewport size to run or not run the plugin?

Comment: No I didn’t add any conditional like that